# Referencing texels in a data texture using indexes in the shader

Tags: three.js, glsl, textures, shader

I have values in the texels of a DataTexture that I am trying to access using indexes in my shader. The indexes `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... 62, 63]` are continuous, while the data texture has a height and width (`uTextureDimension`) of 8. After some research I wrote this function to take a particular index value, and reference the corresponding texel:

```
vec2 customUV = vec2( mod(aIndex, uTextureDimension) / uTextureDimension, floor(aIndex / uTextureDimension) / uTextureDimension );
vec4 texelValues = texture2D( tDataTexture, customUV ).xyzw;
```

I also tried this version to reference the texel from its center point. Also no dice:

```
vec2 perMotifUV = vec2( mod( aIndex, uTextureDimension ) * (( 1.0 / uTextureDimension )/2.0), floor( aIndex / uTextureDimension ) * (( 1.0 / uTextureDimension )/2.0) );
vec4 texelValues = texture2D( tDataTexture, customUV ).xyzw;
```

After working with this since yesterday afternoon, editing it here and there, and looking around for other solutions, I'm still not getting the expected results. I should say that in using Three.js, the shaders are set to high precision float - is this part of the problem? Can anyone nudge me on track here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one seems right, if everything is a float.  Are you using NEAREST filter mode?  Technically you should also add a half-texel-size offset too:

```
vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / uTextureDimension;
vec2 customUV = vec2( mod(aIndex, uTextureDimension)*texelSize, floor(aIndex / uTextureDimension)*texelSize );
customUV += vec2(0.5*texelSize);
```

EDIT - Also your indices should go 0-63 not 0-64

Comment: As a follow-up, should this approach work for DataTextures where the height and width are different. I assume you'd have two texture dimensions and two corresponding texel sizes.