# If I fetch from the texCoord "0, 0", do I fetch from the center of the top-leftmost texel?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

What happens when I fetch (via `texture()`) from the texCoord "0, 0"? I have 2 hypotheses.

1. I fetch from the center of the top-leftmost texel
2. I fetch half a texel to the left and top of the top-leftmost texel. The results depend on the wrapping mode.

Which one is true?

It's surprisingly hard to find info on that.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031945/122687) from which I can deduce that "2." is true. But the answerer there gives no reference.

Comment: in b4 [datenwolf's standard 'fencepost' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879551/44729) :)

Comment: Neither; OpenGL uses bottom-left ordering.