# Addressing Texel in ThreeJS DataTexture

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, compute-shader

I'm looking to compute texel references for a THREE.DataTexture in Javascript for use in a fragment shader. I've succeeded in computing screen space coordinates of points and passing them to a shader in a uniform float array of x and y values, and then referencing those points by indices in my shader. I now want to render too many points to pass the coordinates in a uniform float array so I'd like to use a DataTexture and write the coordinates in the RG values of RGBA texels.

[Referencing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031802/referencing-texels-in-a-data-texture-using-indexes-in-the-shader) I am using the following method:

```
var tDataWidth = points.length;
var tData = new Uint8Array( Math.pow(tDataWidth, 2) );

var texelSize = 1.0 / tDataWidth;
var texelOffset = new THREE.Vector2(0.5 * texelSize, 0.5 * texelSize);

for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){

    //convert data to 0-1, then to 0-255
    //inverse is to divide by 255 then multiply by width, height respectively

    tData[i * 4] = Math.round(255 * (points[i].x / window.innerWidth));
    tData[i * 4 + 1] = Math.round(255 * ((window.innerHeight - points[i].y) / window.innerHeight));
    tData[i * 4 + 2] = 0;
    tData[i * 4 + 3] = 0;

    //calculate UV texel coordinates here
    //Correct after edit
    var u = ((i % tDataWidth) / tDataWidth) + texelOffset;
    var v = (Math.floor(i / tDataWidth) + texelOffset);
    var vUV = new THREE.Vector2(u, v);
    //this function inserts the reference to the texel at the index into the shader
    //referenced in the frag shader:
    //cvec = texture2D(tData, index);
    shaderInsert += ShaderInsert(vUV, screenPos.x, window.innerHeight - screenPos.y);

}
var dTexture = new THREE.DataTexture( sdfUItData, tDataWidth, tDataWidth, THREE.RGBAFormat, THREE.UnsignedByteType );
//I think this is necessary
dTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
dTexture.needsUpdate = true;

//update uniforms of shader to get this DataTexture
renderer.getUniforms("circles")["tData"].value = dTexture;

//return string insert of circle
//I'm editing the shader through javascript then recompiling it
//There's more to it in the calling function, but this is the relevant part I think

    ...

ShaderInsert(index){
     var circle = "\n\tvIndex = vec2(" + String(index.x) + ", " + String(index.y) + ");\n";
     circle += "\tcvec = texture2D(tData, vIndex);\n";
     circle += "\tcpos = vec2( (cvec.r / 255.0) * resolution.x, (cvec.y / 255.0) * resolution.y);\n";
     circle += "\tc = circleDist(translate(p, cpos), 7.0);\n";
     circle += "\tm = merge(m, c);";
     return(circle);    
}
```

Any help on where I'm going wrong? Right now output is all in the lower left corner, so (0, window.innerHeight) as far as I can tell. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't posted enough code. I have no clue what `shader.insert(index)` means. Normally you pass data into shaders vs attributes, uniforms, or other textures. The calculation for a texel though is `uv = (x + 0.5) / textureWidth, (y + 0.5) / textureHeight` so your calculation is slightly off but I doubt that's the real issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27439675/128511

Comment: Thanks @gman! I'll take a look at the question you referenced. I added some code to show what shader.insert() does. I was more trying to focus my question, but if you think my problem may lay elsewhere then you need more info. There's a bit more to to insert that string into the base shader, but the added portion is where the index is referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is actually straightforward. In the fragment shader rgba values are 0.0 - 1.0, so there's no need to divide by 255 as I was doing in the fragment shader.

I'd also like to say that I discovered the Spector.js Chrome extension which allows one to view all webgl calls and buffers. Pretty cool!

[image]

If anyone wants to learn more about how the drawing functions work in the fragment shader, it's all in this awesome shader which I did not write:

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4dfXDn

<3